# Keycloak: Receiving a "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri" when reloading the page manually

Tags: angular, keycloak

It's an Angular 17 SPA Application. And it's using the currently most recent version of keycloak-angular (at time of writing 15.2.1) It's something that I simply do not understand. In the default setup, I can authenticate just fine and logout. But if I dare reload the page, the entire page bricks and on inspection I noticed I receive a 400 Bad Request error. "Invalid parameter: redirect_uri" it says. But why?

My configuration looks for the most part the same as the example from the project, so I do not understand what the issue could be.

[image]

```
function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: 'https://local.dev.auth/',
        realm: 'my-test',
        clientId: 'my-app'
      },
      initOptions: {
        flow: 'standard',
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
          window.location.origin + 'ui/assets/silent-check-sso.html'
      }
    });
}
```

For my testing purposes, I even kept the locally running docker instance of keycloak dirt simple

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the client details correctly both in the Keycloak client and in the angular app. For my app redirect uri is kept as `/` then it gets redirected by my routing startegy, you'll have to update as per your strategy
You should define in this format
[image]

and for the `silentCheckSsoRedirectUri` I've used the Identity providers RedirectURI which you can get from

(Sidenav)Identity Providers->"your provider"->Redirect URI

Also for Keycloak Init you'll have to use `valid_redirect_url` which as per my config is `http://localhost:4200/`

```
initOptions: {
        flow: 'standard',
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        redirectUri: valid_redirect_url,
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: valid_sso_redirect_url
      }
```

Comment: The init options weren't as important. But for some reason, the Access Settings did it for me. Thank you!